# UV editor showing colours as hazy

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I've been following along with Imphenzias video on Low Poly modelling and when i get the part of picking colour in the UV editor the colours are hazy and cloudy. like steam on a mirror if that makes sense? i'm very very new to Blender so i haven't probably tried enough in terms of fixing it, but i have noticed that this effect isn't shown in tabs such as 'Texture paint' 'shading' and 'animation' so i think its only an issue within UV editor.

here's the link to the video if you want to see exactly what i did: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHUY3qoBu8&t=236s

the part that i'm talking about is around 2:10 and goes till 4:50.

Cheers :D

edit: added photos

1.
[image]

2. this is what the colour should look like
   [image]

Comment: hey , thanks i added some photos. let me know if i need anything else

Answer (score 2):

Edit mode has a light grey overlay that affects colors.
You can disable it in the Overlay menu > Faces (uncheck)

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! :D

Comment: Hey :). Glad it helped, you can mark it as accepted ✔ if i solved your problem.